# How to apply collation changes from SQL Alter script to EER model?

Tags: mysql-workbench, eer-model

I'm experiencing troubles while trying to change collations of existing tables in my EER model inside MySQL Workbench (5.2.40, rev 8790) on Linux Debian (3.2.41-2).

My alter script looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_db`.`articles` COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE `my_db`.`articles_tags` COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE `my_db`.`articles_tags_assignment` COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

etc. for approximately hundreds of tables.

When I go to **File** > **Import** > **Reverse Engineer MySQL Create Script...**
and select the script described above, push "Execute", it says "Import finished".

But actually when I go to **Database** > **Synchronize Model...** click through all details and get to differences... then I see that it still thinks, that my EER model have the old collation (latin1_swedish_ci).

Am I doing something wrong or should I just report this as a bug in MySQL workbench?

Comment: Not sure the "Reverse Engineer MySQL **Create** Script" feature is expected to support `ALTER` statements.

Comment: Can't table collation and field collation be different? Did you look at a field or at the table itself?

Answer (score 0):

As the menu entry says, MySQL Workbench expects a create script, that is a script containing CREATE statements. If you only want to change a handful collations just do it in the table editor. Mass changes are a bit more difficult as you can do that only with a plugin in script. There's a plugin for changing the storage engine of all tables. Maybe this can help you to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will work, but is worth a try if anyone else is trying to achieve something like the above:

- Use "forward engineer" to create an instance of the database as described in your model
- Execute your alter script on the instance you've created
- Use "synchronize model" and change all the actions to "update model" to import the changes back into workbench